# Entity Framework not deleting rows from other tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

At present when I try to delete a `Subject`, it gets deleted but the rows from the other tables that correspond to this subject are left behind orphaned.

Here is my model

```
public class SubjectsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FaceImage> EnrolledFaces { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<KVPair> KeyValuePairs { get; set; }

    public SubjectsDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public SubjectsDbContext()
    {
    }
}

public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual FaceImage EnrolledFace {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset EnrolledTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string BiometricId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<KVPair> KeyValues { get; set; }

    public Subject()
    {
        KeyValues = new List<KVPair>();
    }
}

[Table("SubjectFaces")]
public class FaceImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid FaceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}

[Table("SubjectData")]
public class KVPair
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid KvPairId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I try to delete the `Subject`, the rows from the table `SubjectFaces` and `SubjectData` are not deleted.

```
 var subject = dbContext.Subjects.Where(a => a.SubjectId == subjectId).FirstOrDefault();

 if(subject != null)
 {
     dbContext.Subjects.Remove(subject);
 }
 else
 {
     throw new Exception($"Subject not found");
 }

 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I think my model is not correct, how can I annotate it correctly?

**UPDATE:**

After Chris's response I have changed my model to this

```
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual FaceImage EnrolledFace {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset EnrolledTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string BiometricId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<KVPair> KeyValues { get; set; }

    public Subject()
    {
        KeyValues = new List<KVPair>();
    }
}

[Table("SubjectFaces")]
public class FaceImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid FaceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(SubjectId))]
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }
}

[Table("SubjectData")]
public class KVPair
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid KVPairId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(SubjectId))]
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }
}
```

However when I try to create a new `Subject`, I get this exception now.

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'SubjectId'

Been banging my head on this for hours trying different things. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth reading some basics of EntityFramework at https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx.

Your Model needs some modifications as to perform a cascade delete you will need to cross reference one model in another. This is missing in SubjectFaces table.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you still need more work. Entity classes are not complete. Read more about code first entity classes here.
[Entity framework initial application](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-console-application.aspx)

When you refer an entity in Subject class, you also need to refer the Subject in the child entity.

```cs
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual long EnrolledFaceId {get;set;} //
    [ForeignKey("EnrolledFaceId")]
    public virtual FaceImage EnrolledFace {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset EnrolledTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string BiometricId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<KVPair> KeyValues { get; set; }

    public Subject()
    {
        KeyValues = new List<KVPair>();
    }
}
```

```cs
[Table("SubjectFaces")]
public class FaceImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid FaceId { get; set; }

    //Add a reference to the Subject
    [Required]
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public long SubjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[Table("SubjectData")]
public class KVPair
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid KvPairId { get; set; }

    //Add a reference to the Subject
    [Required]
    public long SubjectId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubjectId")]
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I get an exception when I try to create a new Subject. {"Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'webconsole.Models.FaceImage' and 'webconsole.Models.Subject'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."}

Comment: I have modified the solution by adding the foreign key references. In EF, relationships can be done in few different ways.

Comment: Check this to more about Entity framework relationships, https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to structure your entities that make this easier, however to start off with lets add a method to your `SubjectsDbContext` class to use fluent notation to enforce the cascade delete behaviour:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Normally these conventions should easily target your entire model to support cascade delete
    //modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention());
    //modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention());

    // However you many not want the entire model to cascade, 
    // or due to the relationshipships not being explicitly defined so the above conventions
    // may not resolve correctly.
    // These statements explicitly define the relationships and the cascade operation
    modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().HasMany(x => x.KeyValues).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().HasRequired(x => x.EnrolledFace).WithRequiredPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

---

Your Model seems to have the minimal fields necessary to support it, however you have not included any foreign keys in the *Dependent* tables so the model does not *know* that the related records *MUST* depend on their linking to a `Subject`.

In fact by *NOT* specifying the relationship, the model *assumes* that the related keys that it generates on your behalf are in fact *optional*, meaning that `FaceImage` and `KVPair` records are supposed to exist on their own, not linked to a `Subject`.

Adding the Foreign Key links in the `FaceImage` and `KVPair` reduces the abiguity:
*NOTE: only the navigation properties have been added here*

```
public class FaceImage
{
    ...

    [Required]
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
}

public class KVPair
{
    ...

    [Required]
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
}
```

With this change, to target these relationships in the `OnModelCreating` method we need to change the fluent notation slightly:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().HasMany(x => x.KeyValues).WithRequired(x => x.Subject).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().HasRequired(x => x.EnrolledFace).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Subject).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

(Or you could just un-comment the lines that add the *delete cascade* conventions.)

There is a final derivation of this, if you need access to the actual *Foreign Key* fields that are used to enforce the navigation links, or if this is a *Code First* implementation and you want to influence the names of these fields, then you simply add those fields into the classes as well:

```
public class FaceImage
{
    ...

    [Required]
    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(SubjectId))]
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
}

public class KVPair
{
    ...

    [Required]
    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(SubjectId))]
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly I just needed to modify by model as per your last code changes. I have done this, please see my question edits with the latest model. However I get an exception when I try to create a Subject now.

Comment: 2 things to try: 1. Change the `WithRequiredPrincipal` to `WithRequiredDependent`... if that works, then I need to edit this response! 2. Do not specify the `SubjectId` columns. 3. Try to only use the conventions.  I don't ahve a live model or DB to run this against, so EF generates the missing elements when I first create the model.